# Finding average power signal and its calculation

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory

[image: power signal]

Maybe I missed the critical section of fundamental of calculus. I don't get intuitively why finding average power is different if you separate the region like 1,2 and calculating the average of two then adding, versus finding the whole area then dividing the whole length. What makes it different? Isn't it the same process? Why do I have to divide 2 again to my calculated average?

Picture at the bottom summarize what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will type out the response I put in a comment (and then deleted again) because I felt like it would benefit from a bit more extended explaining:

As an analogy to the two methods shown here:

We go shopping - We go by store A and store B. At the end of the day, we bought 8 products, and we spent a total of 20 Space Bucks. Our average is thus 2.5 Space Bucks per product.

In the method on the left, we look at the averages of the individual stores, and then use those to calculate the total average.

In store A, we buy 4 (=L) items and we pay 8 Space Bucks. That means that the average cost in store A was $$ \frac{8 \  Space\ Bucks}{4 \ Products} =\ 2\ \frac{Space\ Bucks}{Product}$$

In store B we again buy 4 products (same L!), but we pay 12 Space Bucks. This gives us a average cost in store B of 3 Space Bucks per product.

Now we want to find the average of the total shopping we did today. What you are doing on the left of your page would be just adding the two averages up. That would in our case result in $$ Average\ Cost = 2 + 3 = 5\ Space\ Bucks$$
Which is clearly not the correct answer!
The correct answer would be 
$$ Average\ Cost = \frac{Average\ cost\ in\ A + Average\ cost\ in\ B}{2} = 2.5\ Space\ Bucks$$

While a silly analogy, I hope it sheds light on the confusion you are having.

Comment: Using your analogy, if I were to go to 4 stores and average each store separately. The total average cost would be just adding 4 averages together then divide by 4? I'm confused because I just read that you can't just add individual averages then take another average of the sum.

Comment: You can only add averages together when they are over the same amount. If we were buying say 5 products in one store and 2 in the other, we can't just take the average of the two (we would have to take 5/7 th of the first store, and 2/7th of the second store)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer using two areas is incorrect. The power for each one is also area divided by 2L and not by L.

Comment: Why is it divided by 2L? The definite integral is from 0 to L for each part. Therefore don't I have to divide the area by that much too?

Comment: The average power over two lengths is not the sum of the two but the sum devided by two!

Comment: @Joren Vaes Do I have to take average of an average? Why doesn't two average added make up for whole average? Is it because they are weighted differently?

Comment: When you separate the signal in two you are building a new signal that has some value (for example, the rectangle) for L and of zero the rest of the time. The average of this part has to be taken over two L.